# Polynomials / curve fitting

Tags: polynomials

I literally don't even understand the question and have no recollection we ever went through solving something similar in my math class
can someone explain me the question or direct me to a link that can help?

The exercise:

> In the set of polynomials of the form
> $$P(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e, x \in \mathbb{R}$$
> where the coefficients {a, b, c, d, e} are arbitrary real numbers, we consider the subset M
> that consists of polynomials, the graphs of which go through all of the following points:
> (−2, 4), (−1, 0), (1, −2) and (3, −6)
>
> a) Does M contain any polynomials of degree lower than 4? If so, list them.
> b) Write down the set of all possible coefficients for the polynomials in M, in standard parametric form.
> c) Find two polynomials in M that have mutually orthogonal tangent lines at the
> point (1, −2).

Comment: You might look up [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

The task is, to put in the 4 Points, then you get 4 equations for the five coefficients a to e. So there is no unique solution.
Lower then  grad 4? if there is a solution with a=0.
Since you have many solutions, take P' at the given point and determine $P_1(1)'=-1/P_2'(-1)$

Comment: but i can get the coefficents by placing the 4 equations in an augmented matrix?

Comment: I don't know what an "augmented" matrix is but linear equations can be solved with  matrix method. Its just 4 linear equations so why ask how to solve?

Comment: i didn't what i was asked to do lol